# Will performBlock act as operation Queue?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a NSMutableArray which insert data every 20 sec, it inserts 10 records at a time. I need to save these 10 records at a time in the child thread.

```
  NSMutableArray *fill = <fill 10 records data in every 20 sec. >

   if [fill count] == 10) {
   [moc performBlock:^{
     for(data in fill)// Now there is 10 elements
    {
        //Fetch something
        //Process data
       //Save
     }
    }];
  fill =nil;
  }
```

But if the process in the block exceeds 20 seconds, "**fill**" will start to insert, and now "**fill**" have 10+ elements, So my question is will it affect the inside of block? or inside of block **fill** have still 10 elements?

Comment: What is operation queue and what particular feature of operation queue do you mean to use here ? Do you mean the concurrency feature of operation queue or to be able to execute limited operation at a time ? Please make it clear.

Comment: i mean both the concurrency feature of operation queue and to be able to execute limited operation at a time . Which one is possible here? if new data comes, will it allow to pass without completing first process finish ?

Comment: NSManagedObjectContext has two different version of performBlock, performBlock: and performBlockAndWait: which will allow you to achieve both of these scenarios

Answer (score 0):

First of all if time of the block exceeds 10s and you insert objects in fill array somewhere else, you are still enumerating it at the same time. This leads to exception, because you are not allowed to modify while enumerating. What about making a copy of the array and perform operations on it?

Something like:

```
NSMutableArray *fill = <fill 10 records data in every 20 sec. >

if [fill count] == 10) {
  NSArray *fillCopy = [fill copy];
  [fill removeAllObjects];
  [moc performBlock:^{
     for(data in fillCopy)// Now there is 10 elements
     {
       //Fetch something
       //Process data
       //Save
     }
  }];
 }
```